# Disabling Alt as meta key in Emacs also disables moving part of word

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

In emacs on my Mac I've switched the meta key from <kbd>Alt</kbd> (<kbd>Option</kbd>) to <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

The problem with this is that I can't any longer move forward or backward part of word when pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>

Is there someway I can enable that functionality and still have <kbd>Esc</kbd> as my meta key?

My .emacs file:

```
(setq mac-option-modifier 'nil)
(setq mac-esc-modifier 'meta)
```

Comment: I don't use a Mac, but do you have to turn off the option-modifier here? Can you leave meta tied to option and add it to Esc at the same time, or are you trying to use option for something else?

Comment: If I dont have `(setq mac-option-modifier 'nil)` then meta will still be bound to option. I want option to be able to move a whole word while pressing option and one of the arrow keys

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. By default, Meta-right and Meta-left (bound to option-right and option-left) will move you by words. Can you do both (setq mac-option-modifier 'meta) and (setq mac-esc-modifier 'meta)?

Comment: Yeah I can but I only want esc to be Meta. Can I bind the move by words function to option-left and option-right?

Comment: My recommendation would be to simply define additional functions as being assigned to the escape modifier key, and remove any definitions that you don't like that are assigned to the meta key, and then forget about trying to change the stock modifier keys.